# how to save data into mongodb using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

*Trying to create `signin` and `signup` using express and MongoDB. In postman the data is perfectly passed but  couldn't save the data into mongoDB cluster.*
*IN this file connection to the db is created and also confused whether i am connected to the db or not* **in this file, I created schema for the user details to be provided**

```
//Index.js


const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const db = process.env.DATABASE;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParse: true }, () =>
  console.log("connected to db")
);



//midlewares
app.use(express.json());

//importing routes

const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

//route middle wares
app.use("/api/user", authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("gg server is running"));



//User.js


const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    max: 32,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 32,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    max: 1022,
    min: 8,
    required: true,
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);




//Auth.js


const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  const name = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
  };

  res.send(user);

  user.save();
});
module.exports = route[![enter image description here][1]][1]r;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1

First, you should create a server after your MongoDB is connected. So, put your server logic inside `mongoose.connect` connect. This will assure that when yo u try to create a new user, MongoDB is already connected.

```js
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParse: true }, () =>
  console.log("connected to db");

  //midlewares
  app.use(express.json());

  //importing routes

  const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

  //route middle wares
  app.use("/api/user", authRoute);

  app.listen(3000, () => console.log("gg server is running"));
);
```

## Step 2

Use `create` method to create new user document:

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  return res.status(200).json(user);
});
```

Comment: Now, it's not sending back response

Comment: Can you try again? I updated my answer. Just copy/paste the whole `register` endpoint handler.

Comment: now, ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.  this error occured. I am puzzled as i am new to mern app

Comment: That means that you are not passing the `password` correctly. Try adding `console.log(req.body)` in the first line of the handler and see what is passed in `req.body`.